# Managed Object Removed from Fetched Results For No Reason

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsfetchrequest, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I've got an odd problem that I can't figure out. I have a fairly typical `UIViewController` with a `UITableView` and an `NSFetchedResultsController` fetching objects from an SQLite store. The fetching works fine and the table works fine, with typical `NSFetchedResultsController` boilerplate:

```
-(void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller{

    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
}
-(void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id<NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type{

    if(type==NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert){
        [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    } else if(type==NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete){
        [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }

}
-(void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath{

    UITableView *tV = self.tableView;
    if(type==NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert){
        [tV insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    } else if(type==NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete){
        [tV deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    } else if(type==NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate){
        [self configureCell:[tV cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] atIndexPath:indexPath];
    } else if(type==NSFetchedResultsChangeMove){
        [tV deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        [tV insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }

}
-(void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller{
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

The problem I'm having is that objects with any relationships that are nil (even if the relationship property is not involved in the fetch request in either the predicate or sort descriptors) disappear from the fetched results (`controller:didChangeObject:` gets called with `NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete`) any time they are updated in any way (changing an unrelated property for instance). If I re-perform the fetch, the object will be back.

This happens even if I don't use a predicate in the fetch request.

Does anybody have any idea what might be going on here?

Comment: there's always a reason, there is nothing like code treason =D

Comment: You should add a description of your entities/attributes/relationships, and also show the code how you create the fetched results controller.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this issue by changing my sectionNameKeyPath on my NSFetchedResultsController. If your sectionNameKeyPath property is an optional relationship property, try removing it or changing it.

You may need to use a "dummy" object to represent nil if you in fact want to use that property to separate the sections. (Which in effect means the property can't be optional if you will be using it for your sections.)

Comment: This is not a true solution until you understand what was the problem.

Comment: The problem is that the sectionNameKeyPath on the NSFetchedResultsController was optional (and thus nil for some objects.) This may not be a solution, but it is at least an explanation of the problem.